# grunt globbing except a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, glob

I have a list of files:

```
 'app/scripts/module.js',
 'app/templates/templates.js',
 'app/scripts/**/*.js'
```

This will load `app/scripts/module.js`, `app/templates/templates.js` and then all the files under `app/scripts/**/*.js` except the one that was loaded before (module.js).
Now I want it to load another file located in `app/scripts/a.js` at the end of the list.
The problem is that when `app/scripts/**/*.js` is loaded, it already load `app/scripts/a.js`.
I want to write something like `app/scripts/**/*.js (!a.js)` - load all except a.js.
It this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to load 'a.js', but after the other scripts?
How about this, (pulled from the [docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns))

```
['app/scripts/**/*.js', '!app/scripts/**/a.js', 'app/scripts/**/a.js' ]
```

If you don't wish to load 'a.js', then just remove the last entry in the array.

```
['app/scripts/**/*.js', '!app/scripts/**/a.js']
```

http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns